# Elastic search aggregation sum of decimal values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have requirement to calculate sum of a price field whose index is {"type": long}. When i calculate sum for price field its giving me 0 instead of 0.5. Following are my json and aggregation query

```
{
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "transaction",
    "_id": "uh5Z-6GBSUez1cRVl5dXpQ",
    "_score": 6.2806625,
    "_source": {
       "txn_id": "8982394",
       "team_id": "4234234234",       
       "price": 0.5,
       "tax": "0.00",
       "gross_price": "0.50",
       "payer_status": "unverified",
       "currency_code": "USD",
       "quantity": "1",             
       "payment_type": "paypal"
    }
}
```

My aggregation query is

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "payment_type": "paypal"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily_price_sum": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query output

```
"aggregations": {
      "daily_price_sum": {
         "value": 0 // Here it is showing sum as 0 instead of 0.5 
      }
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you 
       }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that the price is of type long. When providing 0.5 to a long it's rounds the number, it does not do this mathematically. So the actual value stored is not 0.5 but 0. Make it a double.

Comment: How can i change the filed type without effecting existing data in my collection?

Comment: You cannot, best way would be to create new index with new mapping and reindex the content.